# Need reviews for impacts of dirty bug fix

Tags: ruby, file-system, solaris

I was having a hard time with bug [logstash#665](https://logstash.jira.com/browse/LOGSTASH-665). Hope they will fix it some day, but sparc/solaris support is probably not on top of their priority list. For further reference, original error is:

```
NotImplementedError: stat.st_dev unsupported or native support failed to load dev_major at org/jruby/RubyFileStat.java:190
_discover_file at /tmp/aaaa/logstash-1.4.1.dev/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/filewatch-0.5.1/lib/filewatch/watch.rb:140
```

After digging a lot I found out that the problem here is the usage of a native library which is not correclty retrieved on Solaris. So when ruby fails, it is trying a fallback to java, which fails as well. Now I have retrieved the original [watch.rb source file](https://github.com/jordansissel/ruby-filewatch/blob/690206fd73a5a1b60122c4dca73c2381b55edbcd/lib/filewatch/watch.rb) and isolated the problematic function:

```
private
def _discover_file(path, initial=false)
  globbed_dirs = Dir.glob(path)
  @logger.debug("_discover_file_glob: #{path}: glob is: #{globbed_dirs}")
  if globbed_dirs.empty? && File.file?(path)
    globbed_dirs = [path]
    @logger.debug("_discover_file_glob: #{path}: glob is: #{globbed_dirs} because glob did not work")
  end
  globbed_dirs.each do |file|
    next if @files.member?(file)
    next unless File.file?(file)

    @logger.debug("_discover_file: #{path}: new: #{file} (exclude is #{@exclude.inspect})")

    skip = false
    @exclude.each do |pattern|
      if File.fnmatch?(pattern, File.basename(file))
        @logger.debug("_discover_file: #{file}: skipping because it " +
                      "matches exclude #{pattern}")
        skip = true
        break
      end
    end
    next if skip

    stat = File::Stat.new(file)
    @files[file] = {
      :size => 0,
      :inode => [stat.ino, stat.dev_major, stat.dev_minor],
      :create_sent => false,
    }
    if initial
      @files[file][:initial] = true
    end
  end
end # def _discover_file
```

More precisely, the bug was happening there:

```
    stat = File::Stat.new(file)
    @files[file] = {
      :size => 0,
      :inode => [stat.ino, stat.dev_major, stat.dev_minor],
      :create_sent => false,
    }
```

So I a tried to understand what those two lines do and how to work them around to somehow have something which works. For reference, documentation says:

> dev_major() public
>
> Returns the major part of File_Stat#dev or nil.

After some experimentation, I concluded that since this function can return nil, I could just replace the call of the function by nil like this:

```
stat = File::Stat.new(file)
@files[file] = {
  :size => 0,
  :inode => [stat.ino, nil, nil],
  :create_sent => false,
}
```

Just replaced _stat.dev_major_ and _stat.dev_minor_ by *nil*, launched the program, and it worked. Now I did not test a lot but everything seems to work fine.

So I need your reviews for that last snippet of code which is of my own: The program seems to be bearing with it, but is it really safe to do this?

Comment: Just to be clear — the bug is that `File::Stat.new('/etc/hosts').dev_minor` would cause JRuby to crash with a `NotImplementedError`?

Comment: In my understanding, that part of the code should be used by a ruby equivalent of unix "tail -F" command (see [tail.rb](https://github.com/jordansissel/ruby-filewatch/blob/690206fd73a5a1b60122c4dca73c2381b55edbcd/lib/filewatch/tail.rb) from same source directory), so I would assume that the opened file is the followed one, eg /home/foo/nfsmounts/serverN/myapplication.log. The bug is that the system library containing actual implementation for dev_major/dev_minor is not found on Solaris (although it should exist)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Unix filesystems, an inode is a number that uniquely identifies a file within the filesystem.  (More strictly speaking, an inode is a data structure that holds metadata about a file within the filesystem; each inode is assigned an inode number, and the number is all you care about unless you're a kernel developer.)

However, the inode number only uniquely identifies a file *within its filesystem*.  If `/tmp` and `/usr` are separate filesystems, inode 3461 of the `/tmp` filesystem might be `/tmp/.ICE-unix` while inode 3461 on `/usr` might be `/usr/share/dict/words`.  Therefore, to uniquely identify a file on the whole computer, a tuple of (inode number, device major number, device minor number) is needed.

By ignoring the device number, you might end up acting on events on a file with a coincidentally equal inode number on a different filesystem — though the chance is miniscule.

If you decide to keep this workaround, then I think you should make a corresponding change on [line 71](https://github.com/jordansissel/ruby-filewatch/blob/690206fd73a5a1b60122c4dca73c2381b55edbcd/lib/filewatch/watch.rb#L71) as well.

Comment: What about opening files remotely mounted through NFS? Is their inode the one of the remote file, or the inode of the symbolic link? Because I am considering opening around 30 of them..

Comment: nvm, since it is a system related question, I [posted it](http://superuser.com/questions/741958/from-where-comes-the-inode-number-of-a-file-mounted-through-nfs) on _Super User_ Thanks for your help ;)